# Align text vertically in a image HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-web-developer

I have a image on my personal website where when you hover over it it displays links to my social media pages. However these links go horizontal and don't align in the box. How can I make it so it is vertical and fits in the image.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBLtn.png)

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Socials</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 profile-pic text-center">
<div class="img-box">
<img src="img/myself5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
<ul>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/landn.dev/"><li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>@landn.dev</li></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/LandenMick"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>@LandenMick</li></a>   
<a href="https://github.com/landenthemick"><li><i class="fa fa-github"></i>@landenthemick</li></a>   
</ul>
</div>    
    <h2>Landen Mick</h2>
    <p>Programmer</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If is the issue is resolved by adding `<li>` opening tags, please delete the question voluntarily. SO guidelines require us to close and delete typo caused issues as they have no value to the SO community. If you have further issues/question please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I just saw that you added the `<li>` tag after the links not forgot to add them at all. However this still is an invalid HTML use. the `<li>` has to be right after the `ul` or `ol` tag. They have to be in front of the the `a` tag